# Rendering html partial inside js partial leads to crash

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial

I've encountered a rather strange error when trying to render html partial inside a js partial

In my index page I have:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <%= render :partial => "index", :formats => [:js] %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

And here is  the _index.js.erb file

```
$(function(){
<% if @badge %>
$('#badge').html("<%= j render :partial => "badge1", :badge=> @badge, :user =>     current_user %>");
$('#badge').show().delay(3000).fadeOut(2000);
<% end %>
$('#Container_2').mixItUp();
$('#Container_2').mixItUp('sort', 'myorder:desc');
});
```

When I go to the index page, it gives me the error "Missing partial index". The log says that index.js.erb has been rendered.
However, if I delete line 3 in the _index.js.erb file, it works fine.

So, even if I somehow messed up with the badge partial (which I doubt I did), why does it say it cannot find the whole partial when this line is present?

Comment: What is the filename of the badge1 partial? And where is it stored compared to the index partial and the index view that it is within?

Comment: @philnash It's _badge1.html.erb. It is stored in the same folder with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies with being unable to properly render the badge1 partial.  Try the following:

Make sure there are values for @badge and current_user.

'badge1', locals: {badge: @badge, user: current_user}) %>

Comment: Yep, for some reason current_user method messes things up, so I passed user from controller instead, and it works now. Thanks!

However, why didn't rails say that it couldn't render badge1 partial and instead said it cannot find the index partial?

Comment: That error message is totally weird for the error that you're getting. I was obviously off down the wrong track with my comment!